# How to Implement A Basic Search in Dicts

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, search

I have a list of dicts as below:

```
[
    {"name":"Some", "surname":"Body","age":22},
    {"name":"Some", "surname":"One", "age":23},
    {"name":"Any", "surname":"Body", "age":20}
]
```

I need a function which makes search over dicts as below:

```
def search(data:dict, **kwargs):
    pass

search(mydict, surname="Body")
[
    {"name":"Some", "surname":"Body","age":22},
    {"name":"Any", "surname":"Body", "age":20}
]

search(mydict, name="Some")
[
    {"name":"Some", "surname":"Body","age":22},
    {"name":"Some", "surname":"One", "age":23}
]

search(mydict, age=23)
[
    {"name":"Any", "surname":"Body", "age":20}
]
```

How can I achieve that?

---

### Environment

- Python 3.5

Comment: If you actually want to pass a combinations of key,value pairs in `search` this might be more interesting...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, or tutorial service.

Comment: That's why I've used `**kwargs`?

Comment: Yes, well, your *examples* don't suggest that you do. And we cannot guess exactly what you want. It is best if you do your best to specify your problem. For example, do you want *any* of those key, value pairs to hold? Or *all* f them?

Comment: IMO, this might not be a dupe, as the cases in the dupe target are not multivalued

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using `all` to test for dictionaries that contain the exact key-value in `kwargs`:

```
lst = [
    {"name":"Some", "surname":"Body","age":22},
    {"name":"Some", "surname":"One", "age":23},
    {"name":"Any", "surname":"Body", "age":20}
]


def search(data:dict, **kwargs):
    return [d for d in data if all(d[k]==v for k, v in kwargs.items())] 

print(search(lst, surname="Body", age=22))
# [{'name': 'Some', 'age': 22, 'surname': 'Body'}]
```

You can use the `.get` method of the dict to handle missing keys and then pass a sentinel object as default:

```
def search(data:dict, **kwargs):
    return [d for d in data if all(d.get(k, object())==v for k, v in kwargs.items())]
```

Comment: I might be inclined to use `all(d.get(k, object()) == v....`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Nice one. Thanks!